# How can I add two related nested instance in one request using DRF?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm new to Django rest framework

I have two models:

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(("name"), max_length=50)
    long = models.CharField(("longitude"), max_length=50)
    lat = models.CharField(("latitude"), max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Farm (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(("Name"), max_length=50)
    size = models.FloatField('Size')
    size_unit = models.CharField(("Size Uint"), max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account,  on_delete=models.SET('Deleted user'))
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET('Deleted Location'))
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

And serializers:

```py
class FarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Farm
        fields = '__all__'


class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can I create both Farm and location in one request like this:

```json
{
  "name": "new farm",
  "size": 400,
  "size_unit": "meter",
  "owner": 1,
  "location":[
         {
             "name":"new location",
             "long":2132.123212,
             "lat":2213231.1234
         }
       ]
    }
```

I've tried to add create at serializer like:

```py
def create(self,validated_date):
    location_data = validated_date.pop('location')
    location = Location.objects.get_or_create(**location_data)
    farm = Farm.objects.create(**validated_date,location=location)
    return farm
```

But it does not work and it gives me this message

```json
{
   "location": [
       "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you placed this parameter to the `location` field: `SET('Deleted Location')` what does it means?

Comment: how about `owner` field? doesn't it need creating?

Comment: I placed SET('Deleted Location') so that if the Location is deleted the Farm is not deleted as I needed in future measures @EliasPrado

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set the `LocationSerializer` in `FarmSerializer`.

```
class FarmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = LocationSerializer(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Farm
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I think `Farm` model has only one `Location`, so the `location` is not the array in JSON data.

```
{
    "name": "new farm",
    "size": 400,
    "size_unit": "meter",
    "owner": 1,
  
    "location":{
                "name":"new location",
                "long":2132.123212,
                "lat":2213231.1234
    }
}
```